# Kernel panic after boot Centos 6.5 HP DL320 B120i HPVSA

Tags: centos, raid, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, fakeraid

Im working with a new HPDL320 micro server (gen8-2) with a HP Dynamic array B120i

My problem is after the setup.
I provided the DiskDrive to the installer and everything is fine. at first i used kick start version but now im having the same issue with a fresh centos 6.5 x86_64 install.

the boot dies in the initrd, I added rdshell and removed el quiet and rghb options from the grub option just to find that the root device was not found.

blkid shows nothing

I tried to create a software raid but the problem was the same. dracut could not see the md devices so it would not boot.

what i tried.

Fresh uninstall centos 6.5 DD 
Kickstatt install centos 6.2 DD